# Using awk to count names in a column

Tags: awk

Indicates the initials of people who have three proper names;

so, i have a column in this case it's

```
awk -F ';' '{print $1, $2}' users.txt

output:
   xxx  JoaoPedroVilar
   xxa  JoaoMiguel
   RMF  RitaPereira
   ....
```

My question is: i need with function count ( i guess) , so count only in the column $2 which names have more than 2 names... because i just want in the output Acronyms and names with 2 plus letter upppercases like this:

```
xxx JoaoPedroVilar
RAT RicardoAntonioPereira
```

Sample data:

```
awk -F ';' '{print $1, $2}' users.txt 

Output:
xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx HugoFernandes
xxx HugoGomes
xxx In�sSilva
xxx Jo�oTeixeira
xxx JoaquimGon�alves
JAR JoaquimRibeiro
xxx Jos�PedroRafael
xxx Jos�Soares
xxx LuisFernandes
xxx MiguelMadeira
xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx PedroLucasFarinha
```

the answer is :

```
awk -F';' -b '$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*/{print $1, $2}' users.txt
```

So -b it's just awk interpret all caracthers

Comment: I don't understand. What is the input? What is the output? Where does the `RAT RicardoAntonioPereira` line come from? `names with 2 plus` what is a "name with 2 plus"? What is a "2 plus"? `Name2+`?

Comment: name with 2 plus, letter uppercase

Comment: RAT - RicardoAntonioPereira it's just an example..
In my output with AWK, i only want the acronyms and the names of the person's they have 3 names or more..
So the output like : JoaoMiguel cannot return. only 3 names, or more

Comment: Just for clarification. You are looking for rows in your file where the second column contains 3 or more upper case letters?

Comment: yes, i just want the output of in column 3 i have 3 or more upper case letters

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make sure the expected output you provide can be produced from the sample input you provide. Don't provide sample input and then output from some different input. Keep it simple.

Comment: `[A-Z]` isn't necessarily the set of upper case letters btw - `[[:upper:]]` is. What `[A-Z]` means all depends on your locale setting. Also, `[A-Z]{1}` is just `[A-Z]` and you don't need `.*` of the regexp at the end since that means zero-or-more reps of any character so it matches zero chars or any chars. So `$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*/` is equivalent to just `$2~/[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z]/`

Answer (score 0):

This regex can probably be refactored, but it does the trick (I think)

```
 awk -F';' '$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*/{print $1, $2}' users.txt
```

That's just matching for 3 single upper case characters in your second column. Note that this is going to have false positives if you have names like `ScottMcMasters` or `BobO'Neal` but trying to seperate names that aren't already separated is never 100%.

Example:

```
  cat users.txt
xxx;JoaoPedroVilar
xxx;PedroAndrePereira
RAT;RicardoAntonioPereira
xxx;BobBob
xxx;SomeName
  awk -F";" '$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*/' users.txt
xxx;JoaoPedroVilar
xxx;PedroAndrePereira
RAT;RicardoAntonioPereira
```

Comment: thanks, i test this, bue he really give me 1 return.
ex:
PPA PedroAndrePereira.


but i have more names with 3 uppercases, it's just for  one return?

Comment: It should make that test on every row in your file. I just put together a fake `users.txt` with your names and it spit them all out.

Comment: please see the answer i put, maybe i have to put another parameter like -F ";" on AWK to read the special names?

Comment: awk -F";" -b '$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*/' users.txt

i add a -b on AWK and it works

Answer (score 0):

Without testable input/output it's a guess but it sounds like you need:

```
awk -F';' '$2 ~ /([[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]+){2}[[:upper:]]/{print $1, $2}' file
```

e.g. using the output you posted elsewhere to create sample input:

```
$ cat file
xxx;NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx;HugoFernandes
xxx;HugoGomes
xxx;In�sSilva
xxx;Jo�oTeixeira
xxx;JoaquimGon�alves
JAR;JoaquimRibeiro
xxx;Jos�PedroRafael
xxx;Jos�Soares
xxx;LuisFernandes
xxx;MiguelMadeira
xxx;NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx;PedroLucasFarinha
```

.

```
$ awk -F';' '$2 ~ /([[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]+){2}[[:upper:]]/{print $1, $2}' file
xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx Jos�PedroRafael
xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx PedroLucasFarinha
```

If that doesn't work for you then try setting your locale to C first (and next try setting it to whatever local understands the "control chars" in your files as letters) as you're probably just having a locale problem:

```
LC_ALL=C awk -F';' '$2 ~ /([[:upper:]][^[:upper:]]+){2}[[:upper:]]/{print $1, $2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach of counting upper case chars

```
$ awk -F';' 'gsub(/[A-Z]/,"&",$2)>2 {print $1,$2}'
```

Comment: yes, right, regex will match the back-to-back upper cases as well.

Answer (score -1):

with:

```
 awk -F";" '$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*/' users.txt

Output: 
PLF PedroLucasFarinha
```

but when i print just the names i have example:

```
awk -F ';' '{print $1, $2}' users.txt 

Output:
xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx HugoFernandes
xxx HugoGomes
xxx In�sSilva
xxx Jo�oTeixeira
xxx JoaquimGon�alves
JAR JoaquimRibeiro
xxx Jos�PedroRafael
xxx Jos�Soares
xxx LuisFernandes
xxx MiguelMadeira
xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira
xxx PedroLucasFarinha
```

but with :

```
awk -F';' -b '$2~/[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*[A-Z]{1}.*/{print $1, $2}' users.txt
```

the output it's

xxx Jos�PedroRafael

xxx NunoAndr�Ferreira

xxx PedroLucasFarinha

Comment: That's interesting. Can you edit your question and add this information. If you could also post the output of command `file users.txt`. This answer should be closed since it doesn't answer your question, but adds helpful information for folks trying to solve it.

Comment: No, don't add an "answer", provide all relevant information in your question. Keep it simple.